# Is sorting orientation different in VSTO than in VBA (or am I doing something wrong?)

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, vsto

In a VBA project attached to this workbook containing this set of fictitious sales data,
[image: initial appearance of sales data]

I used the following command to sort the records in by branch, date and time:

```
bolge.Sort Key1:=bolge.Cells(1, 1), Key2:=bolge.Cells(1, 4),
    Key3:=bolge.Cells(1, 5), Header:=xlYes
```

The data was sorted as I expected:
[image: sales data after sorted by VBA macro]

When I implemented the same command in a VSTO project:

```
bolge.Sort(bolge.Cells(1, 1), Key2:=bolge.Cells(1, 4),
    Key3:=bolge.Cells(1, 5), Header:=Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes)
```

sorting was done to create an alphabetical order in the header row and columns were shifted accordingly:

[image: sales data order by the same command in VSTO]

The problem in the VSTO project must have been caused by the missing `Orientation` parameter, which should have been

```
Orientation:=Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns
```

not the default value `xlSortRows`.

My short search did not show anyone else encountering this problem. In the MSDN page about the `Range.Sort` function in VBA, nothing is mentioned about the default value for the `Orientation` parameter, but when I search about `XlSortOrientation` enumeration, I find that the default value is the same in VBA. I am wondering why the default behavior is not the same in VSTO. Have I implemented the command incorrectly in my VSTO project?

Comment: I never liked `Orientation` because I never could remember the correct value and always had to experiment. The VBA object browser displays that default value for `Orientation` is `xlSortRows`, but when you omit `Orientation` in VBA, it works as if `xlSortColumns` was passed, and if you explicitly pass the "default" `xlSortRows`, it does the opposite of what it does when you omit `Orientation`. And besides the names of the constants are messed up, `xlSortRows` sorts columns and vice versa. I guess whatever magic is happening in VBA when you omit the value is not happening in VSTO.

Comment: Bottom line is that it appears to be a very old problem in Excel that will never be fixed for compatibility reasons. You need to remember to always explicitly pass `xlSortColumns` in both environments (VBA and VSTO), and just memorize that `xlSortColumns` means "sort rows".

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that means I totally misinterpreted the `xlSortRows` option. I thought that meant "sort rows", i.e. reorder them according to the sorting criteria. Conversely, I would expect `xlSortColumns` to reorder columns, but they both worked in the opposite ways. Definitely counter-intuitive.

Comment: I believe it's a bug. Explicitly passing `xlSortRows` certainly should have the same effect in VBA as omitting `Orientation`, but it does not. The IDL declaration is apparently not telling the truth. Taking that into account, and also the fact that the default `xlSortRows` equals `2` when `xlSortColumns` equals `1`, I believe a mistake was made many years ago when first publishing the type library, they must have swapped `xlSortRows` and `xlSortColumns` in the IDL declaration, but the `Sort` method itself still uses "correct" values (`xlSortRows = 1`, `xlSortColumns = 2`).